# Where Can I find the output of the debug() function displayed?

Tags: debugging

I have written `debug()` in a php file in my local Drupal project. I am trying to see the output. How do I do that?

Comment: where exactly you located the php file that contain `debug()` function?

Answer (score 1):

The output should be logged to the Drupal watchdog (admin/reports/dblog). If you're debugging a variable that is an array or object, don't forget to pass TRUE as the third parameter ([ref](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/debug/7)).

Although the code in question may be in a function cached by Drupal, so sometimes you need to flush the cache to trigger that code to be re-run.

Personally, I prefer using the `dpm()` function from the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module for debugging. If using an account with admin permissions, it displays arrays/objects in a way that is easier to inspect.